# How to retrieve an attr value from an nextAll() retrieved list from one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the deal: I need to look up for an element, on a list of others HTMLElements, for the next one that has the class '.wanted-class'. I fire/capture a `click` event in one of the elements from the same class. I ended up with a solutions that looks like this:

```
$('#id-element-0000').nextAll('.wanted-class');
```

This should return a list of all the elements that belongs to this class that are after the one I clicked. Something like this:

```
<div class=​"wanted-class" id=​"id-element-1111" data-wanted=​"6127">​…​</div>
<div class=​"wanted-class" id=​"id-element-2222" data-wanted=​"6128">​…​</div>
<div class=​"wanted-class" id=​"id-element-3333" data-wanted=​"6129">​…​</div>
<div class=​"wanted-class" id=​"id-element-4444" data-wanted=​"6130">​…​</div>​
```

But, I only want the first one. I don't need the others. So I came up (AKA: found on google) a solution that was simply:

```
$('#id-element-0000').nextAll('.wanted-class')[0];
```

This obviously return this:

```
<div class=​"wanted-class" id=​"id-element-1111" data-wanted=​"6127">​…​</div>
```

That solves the `first element` problem. But, I can't access the `data-wanted` attribute on the element. Something like:

```
$('#id-element-0000').nextAll('.wanted-class')[0].attr('data-wanted');
```

...or...

```
$('#id-element-0000').nextAll('.wanted-class')[0].data('wanted');
```

...simply don't work. And I don't seem to be able to put it into a variable too.

**QUESTION:** does anyone know how to retrieve the `data-wanted` attribute from the first element from this list?

**UPDATE**
Obviously, the better way of doing it was to use `next` intead of `nextAll`, BUT I have others elements between elements from this same class. So, `next` function doesn't apply in this case. And, YES... I've tried.

Comment: When you use `[number]` on a jQuery object, it returns the DOM element. It is no longer wrapped with jQuery. That's why the jQuery functions don't work.

Comment: Thanks, @Ninsly! I didn't knew that. Thanks for the enlightening! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it with `$()` to convert it to jQuery object:

```
$($('#id-element-0000').nextAll('.wanted-class')[0]).attr('data-wanted');
```

Or simply use

```
$('#id-element-0000').nextAll('.wanted-class').first().attr('data-wanted');
```

When you index over jQuery objects, you will get `HTMLElement` which doesn't have methods that jQuery has.

Comment: The last one worked like a charm! You guys are awesome! Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the first element in the jQuery wrapper set. You should convert it to jQuery object again, or get the first item with `.eq` method which return jQuery object:

```
$('#id-element-0000').nextAll('.wanted-class').eq(0).attr('data-wanted');
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/e2pme9f6/).